# Split datetime records that fall between 10pm to 7am into new record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query, date-math

I am very new to SQL Server. I am trying to split time in time out records that fall between night shifts from a employee shifts table but I am having a difficult time doing so. Night Shift runs from 10pm to 7am.

Example below might help make things clearer.

E.g

```
EmployeeId   InTime                     OutTime                  
----------   -----------------------    ----------------------- 
1            2018-08-10 21:00:00.000   2018-08-11 09:00:00.000
```

Desired Output

```
    EmployeeId   InTime                     OutTime                   Type
    ----------  -----------------------    -----------------------   -------
    1            2018-08-10 21:00:00.000    2018-08-10 22:00:00.000   day
    1            2018-08-10 22:00:00.000    2018-08-11 07:00:00.000   night
    1            2018-08-11 07:00:00.000    2018-08-11 09:00:00.000   day
```

code for current table:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE 
    (
        EmployeeId INT,
        InTime DATETIME,
        OutTime DATETIME
    )

INSERT INTO @tbl(Employee_Id,Shift_Start,Shift_end) VALUES (1,'2018-08-10 21:00:00.000','2018-08-11 09:00:00.000')
```

Comment: To be completely honest I have no idea where to even start.

Comment: Is 10pm and 7am is static. Is that the only criteria for night shift. Can someone be late and come at 11pm  and end at 9am?

Comment: Yes they can. So if an employee comes in at 11pm and ends at 9am, only the hours between 11pm to 7am will be be classed as a night shift the remaining time 7am - 9am will be a day shift.

Comment: @zeena, 11 pm to 7 am is night and 7 am to 9 pm is the day. what about `9 pm to 11 pm`?

Comment: @Bijujose, any hours worked between the hours 10pm and 7pm are night. E.g if the shift runs from  9pm to 11pm he shift will need to be split,  9pm - 10 pm as day and 10pm to 11 pm as night.

Comment: @Zeena, so 7 am to 10 pm is day and 10 pm to 7 am is the night. Right?

Comment: @Bijujose, yes correct.

Comment: Please see answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912989/split-time-in-time-out-records-that-fall-between-night-shifts/51917876#51917876

Comment: Are the two dates at most one day apart or could they span multiple days?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its crossposted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51912989/split-time-in-time-out-records-that-fall-between-night-shifts/51917876#51917876

Answer (score 2):

Try using a recursive Common Table Expression (CTE) to generate a list of hours between the minimum and maximum date/times. Then you can use [`DENSE_RANK`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to group the records.

#### Example:

```
WITH
source_data
AS
(
    SELECT tbl.* FROM (VALUES
      ( 1, '10-Aug-2018 21:00', '10-Aug-2018 22:00')
    , ( 2, '10-Aug-2018 20:00', '11-Aug-2018 07:00')
    , ( 3, '11-Aug-2018 07:00', '11-Aug-2018 09:00')
    , ( 4, '10-Aug-2018 20:00', '11-Aug-2018 09:00')
    ) tbl ([EmployeeId], [InTime], [OutTime]) 
)
, 
source_data_dates
AS
(
    SELECT [InTimeMin] = MIN([InTime]), [OutTimeMax] = MAX([OutTime]) FROM source_data
)
,
source_data_times([n], [InTime]) 
AS
(
    SELECT 1, CAST([InTimeMin] AS DATETIME) FROM source_data_dates
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1, [InTimeMin] = CAST(DATEADD(hh, n, [InTimeMin]) AS DATETIME)  FROM source_data_times, source_data_dates WHERE n <= DATEDIFF(hh, [InTimeMin], [OutTimeMax])
)
, 
source_data_times_type
AS
(
    SELECT
          [InTime] = [InTime]
        , [OutTime] = DATEADD(hh, 1, [InTime])
        , [Type] = 
            CASE 
                WHEN CAST([InTime] AS TIME) >= '22:00:00' OR CAST([InTime] AS TIME) < '07:00:00'
                THEN 'night'
                ELSE 'day'
            END
    FROM 
        source_data_times
)
, 
source_data_times_type_rank
AS
(
    SELECT 
          sd.[EmployeeId]
        , tt.[InTime]
        , tt.[OutTime]
        , tt.[Type]
        , [GroupRank] = DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY sd.[EmployeeId] ORDER BY tt.[Type], CAST(tt.[InTime] AS DATE))
    FROM
        source_data AS sd
        INNER JOIN source_data_times_type AS tt ON tt.[InTime] >= sd.[InTime] AND tt.[InTime] < sd.[OutTime]
)
SELECT
      [EmployeeId]
    , [InTime] = MIN([InTime])
    , [OutTime] = MAX([OutTime])
    , [Type]
FROM 
    source_data_times_type_rank
GROUP BY 
      [EmployeeId]
    , [Type]
    , [GroupRank]
ORDER BY
      [EmployeeId]
    , MIN([InTime])
```

#### Results:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: I suggest one avoid using the undocumented `spt_values` table in production code and instead use a user-defined tally table or CTE to generate sequence numbers for common tasks like this. `spt_values` doesn't exist in Azure SQL Database.

Comment: @DanGuzman, good call, I've updated my answer and removed the reference to `spt_values`. It's also now a bit easier to read.